FetchSFTP cant retrieve files correctly: java.io.IOException: error; routing to comms.failure
I'm trying to get a set of file .csv from a directory in a server sftp. My nifi is deployed in a cluster with only one node for nifi. If I try to download a file .csv through sftp> from the same node on which nify is deployed, I can get it without problem. However the processor SFTP in nifi is not able to do it, but I continuosly get the following stacktrace:
    ERROR org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchSFTP: FetchSFTP[id=1f5b3ddd-2d4c-1889-ffff-ffffa3d58254] Failed to fetch content for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=ccf2a3ae-51cc-470c-80e0-6477b045a536,claim=,offset=0,name=file.csv,size=0] from filename /test/nifi on remote host 10.100.201.248:22 due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from FetchSFTP[id=1f5b3ddd-2d4c-1889-ffff-ffffa3d58254]: java.io.IOException: error; routing to comms.failure: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from FetchSFTP[id=1f5b3ddd-2d4c-1889-ffff-ffffa3d58254]: java.io.IOException: error
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from FetchSFTP[id=1f5b3ddd-2d4c-1889-ffff-ffffa3d58254]: java.io.IOException: error
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2647)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFileTransfer.onTrigger(FetchFileTransfer.java:251)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1161)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2.read(ChannelSftp.java:1448)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2.read(ChannelSftp.java:1364)
    at org.apache.nifi.stream.io.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:35)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFileTransfer$1.process(FetchFileTransfer.java:254)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2628)
    ... 13 common frames omitted

Can someone helps me? in the FetchSFTP I put the same  configuration used to get the file using sftp> thus those are correct.
Could it be due to misconfigurations of nifi in the cluster? im using Cloudera

Since it is IO related exception, check whether user configured in FetchSFTP has required permissions
